# Python Beginner problems

Tags: python

So I was writing the following code to reverse a number in python :

```
def intreverse(n):
  m= 0
  while n>0:
    (d,n)= (n%10,n/10)
    m= 10*m + d 
  return(m)
print(intreverse(45))
```

I got my results but I was wondering, since in python we get a float number.But why not in the above case. Like If I take n=45 , then updating the n:=4.5 but python consider it as 4. why?

Comment: What are you expecting this to do?

Comment: You can reverse an `int` in one line: `int(str(n)[::-1])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 2 the division between two integers is interpreted as an integer division that returns an integer (as does `//`). However if one of the two numbers involved in the division is a float, then the operator is interpreted as the float division which returns a float.

In Python 3 the behavior of `/` has been made the same regardless of the type of the numbers involved so you will get a float no matter what, and the integer division is still `//`.

For example in Python 3 you have:

```
>>> 45/10
4.5
>>> 40/10
4.0
>>> 45//10
4
```

But in Python 2 you have:

```
>>> 45/10
4
>>> 40/10
4
>>> 45.0/10
4.5
>>> 45//10
4
```